# Should I create child textviews statically or dynamically?

Tags: android, view, android-listview, children

I have a listview where the items contain different amount of child textviews.

```
min 5
max 20
```

i've tried both ways and I only have the vm to test my apps on so I can't really tell any difference performance wise.

but what's the best way to do this?

should I create the 20 textviews in my xml and just hide the ones I don't use?
or just create and add new textviews everytime, resulting in no "Ghost views"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### Issues to realise:

1. **Code cleanliness-**> Doing anything more than basic layouts in code can get very messy, very fast.
2. **Code re-use**-> It’s extremely easy to inflate an XML layout into a specified view 
   with one or two lines of code
3. **code Performance**-> Creating the objects necessary for an in-code layout leads to unnecessary garbage collection.  As per the Android Designing for Performance article, “avoid creating short-term temporary objects if you can.”
4. **Attribute availability**-> Defining Views in an XML layout exposes attributes that are not always available by object methods.

### Possible disadvantages:

It make take more time to do an XML layout versus defining the layout in code, especially if there are only one or two interface elements that need to be changed.

After thinking about what I want to accomplish, it makes sense for me to use XML layouts for the dynamic view changes I need.  It would be more than just a few lines of code to do my layout changes without utilizing XML layouts.

Now you can decide according to your requirements.

Comment: I'll go for the xml way, to avoid garbage collection... this way it's also less code for me...

Comment: I don't agree. I mean yes, you can inflate the views but in the background Android creates the same objects you'd create manually. They are not short-lived. The views will live as long as the Activity lives.

Comment: Do not create a panic.Vote down is not a solution.Yes they will live as long as activity.So that is short span if your application has 7  8 activities.But i did not get where i mention this "They are short-lived".i said that avoid to create short lived object if you can

Comment: Which doesn't make sense in here. Also I am supposed to down-vote wrong answers. Everyone is actually supposed to do just that.

Comment: can you please elaborate mistake in my code so that i edit it

Comment: In what code? I am commenting on your answer. I have no idea about your code whatsoever.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean:your attitude will harm to community.If you have more reputation that does not mean you behave in that way

Comment: I have no idea what you are on about. I'm just doing my duty to vote on answers based on their correctness. This one just isn't correct. Simple as that.

Comment: @WarrenFaith You may want to join us in the [Android chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15/android) if you have time to.