# Creating CustomViews as a modular & reusable component which can be used across projects

Tags: android, modularity, custom-view

I'm currently in the process of creating quite a large scale Android application. As part of the application I've created a Custom View (one of many).

The Custom View in question is quite wide ranging in terms of functionality and because of that there are an awful lot of layouts, resources & drawable involved to respond to different devices, orientations, resolutions etc.

How can I separate out this functionality so it can be developed in isolation and not contaminate resources in the rest of the project. (Also, make it available to share across projects without having to untangle resource's).

I'm hoping that it is possible to somehow "jar" it all up in some way but fear this may not be possible. It would be great if anyone has any strategies to achieve this.

Comment: go thorugh this link and check my answer.In my opinion use static view as possible..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544380/should-i-create-child-textviews-statically-or-dynamically/8544821#8544821

Comment: @TofeeqAhmad I don't even understand what you are trying to say here, however the answer you've linked to is plain wrong.

Comment: I said that its not better approach to create view and store them.Better to use XML file

Comment: I think you didn't get the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll probably want to look at a [Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).

It lets you share code and resources between applications.

From [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects):

> An Android library project is a development project that holds shared Android source code and resources.
>   Other Android application projects can reference the library project and, at build time, include its compiled sources in their .apk files. Multiple application projects can reference the same library project and any single application project can reference multiple library projects.

Comment: The link provided for Library Projects seems to be out of date. I think this link is a good replacement: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryModules